# Angular ng build --prod causes blank screen in browser

Tags: angular, jwt

When running the ng build --prod command and load the app in the browser, all of the elements that are usually retrieved from the server are not displayed

This is a dotnet core 2.0 project with Angular 5 in the front end
I'm using "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^1.0.0-beta.9"

If I browse to a link on the page, I get the error

```
main.23ac97c628174ee61247.bundle.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Failed to construct 
'URL': Invalid URL
  at t.isWhitelistedDomain (main.23ac97c628174ee61247.bundle.js:1)
  at t.handleInterception (main.23ac97c628174ee61247.bundle.js:1)
  at t.intercept (main.23ac97c628174ee61247.bundle.js:1)
  at t.handle (main.23ac97c628174ee61247.bundle.js:1)
  at t.intercept (main.23ac97c628174ee61247.bundle.js:1)
  at t.handle (main.23ac97c628174ee61247.bundle.js:1)
  at t.handle (main.23ac97c628174ee61247.bundle.js:1)
  at e.project (main.23ac97c628174ee61247.bundle.js:1)
  at e._tryNext (main.23ac97c628174ee61247.bundle.js:1)
  at e._next (main.23ac97c628174ee61247.bundle.js:1)

app.module.ts:

export function getAccessToken(): string {
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

export const jwtConfig = {
  tokenGetter: getAccessToken,
  whiteListedDomains: ['localhost:5000']
};

  imports: [
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: jwtConfig
     }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an open issue: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/477

The problem is caused inside the lib by calling new URL(request.url) with a relative url. You could set your version in the package-json without ^ as beta 9 should work or by removing relative url calls.

Also you have misspelled whitelistedDomains